# Создание шаблона Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет, начинаю изучать Django, пытаюсь создать новый шаблон.
Ошибка: TemplateDoesNotExist.

Код views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Код настроек:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

На вьюшку переходит, просто не находит шаблон. Он расположен в папке templates

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо указать джанго где искать ваши шаблоны. Это делаться через переменную TEMPLATE_DIR

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                 'users.context_processors.add_my_login_form',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Из вопроса не следует, что она не указана. В дефолтно созданном проекте она такая и есть. Другое дело, что лежит ли в директории по умолчанию необходимый шаблон...

Answer (score 0):

Самый просто способ, это изменить 'DIRS' следующим образом

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'название_твоей_директории_с_шаблонами'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                 'users.context_processors.add_my_login_form',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

По дефолту, если директория с шаблонами называется templates, это выглядит так

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                 'users.context_processors.add_my_login_form',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```